# QApplication' is not defined in Pycharm

Tags: python

I've just installed window version Python 3.4.1 x32 and along with it Pycharm. Now I've installed PyQt 4 for Python 3.4.
I've just written some code watching a tutorial and I'm getting an error that

app = Qapplication(sys.argv)
NameError: name 'Qapplication' is not defined`

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import sys


app = Qapplication(sys.argv)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Is it not `QApplication`?

I'm using pyside. In pyside it is `QApplication` instead of `Qapplication`

I think it may be the same in pyqt4

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, it should be:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#      ^
#  uppercase
```

See [QApplication documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qapplication.html)